# MassTransit - Azure Service Bus - MaxDeliveryCount not respected for SubscriptionEndpoint

Tags: azureservicebus, masstransit, azure-servicebus-topics

I'm evaluating fault tolerance in MassTransit using Azure Service bus, where I am trying to build a consumer which will retry a number of times using UseMessageRetry() - to be added, but if that ultimately fails, will repeat that process upto the MaxDeliveryCount of the transport/endpoint.

I have found that the number of retries that Azure service bus attempts is not aligned with the values set, my setup is as follows:

1. A simple consumer which throws an exception (omitted for brevity)
2. MassTransit registered as follows:

```
builder.Services.AddMassTransit(x => 
{
   x.AddConsumer<MyFaultyConsumer>();

   x.UsingAzureServiceBus((context, cfg) => 
   {
       cfg.Host("my-connection");
       cfg.SubscriptionEndpoint("faulty-consumer-sub", "test-topic", endpointConfig =>
    {
            endpointConfig.MaxDeliveryCount = 7;
            // I have also tried the below which didn't result in the expected number of retries
            // endpointConfig.RethrowFaultedMessages();
            endpointConfig.ConfigureConsumer<MyFaultyConsumer>(context);
    }
       cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(context);
   })
}
```

This config sets up a subscription in Azure Service Bus with a MaxDeliveryCount of 7 as expected. When the consumer throws an exception however, rather than the expected 7 retries, I've observed it retry 1 or 3 times.

Is this expected behaviour, or is there some configuration/ordering I've missed in order to achieve the retry strategy described above?

Thanks